Angular 18 SSR with Localisation Breaks Direct URL Access for Routes with Parameters
I’m currently working on an Angular 18 application with server-side rendering (SSR) and localisation (i18n) for en and es. Everything works fine if I navigate within the app using the provided links, but if I attempt to access a URL with a route parameter directly, I receive a 404 error.
My Setup:
Angular 18
SSR enabled (Vercel)
Localisation using i18n (en, es)
Example Routes:
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadComponent: () =>
      import('./components/splash/splash.component').then(
        (c) => c.SplashComponent
      ),
  },
  {
    path: 'items/:itemCode',
    loadComponent: () =>
      import('./components/items/items.component').then(
        (c) => c.ItemsComponent
      ),
  },
];

Problem:
When I navigate to a route with a parameter (like itemCode) within the app using Angular’s router, everything works fine. However, if I try to go directly to a URL with parameters, it throws 404.
https://example.com/en/items/12345
What I’ve Tried:

Building the application without localisation works fine. The issue only arises when I enable localisation via the localize option in the angular.json file.

Verified my SSR server setup. The app works as expected when navigating through Angular’s router.

Non-parameterised routes work fine when accessed directly.


Localisation Setup:
This is my angular.json configuration:
"localize": ["en", "es"],
"outputPath": "dist/app",

When building without localize, the app works fine. Once localisation is added, I see the following folder structure:

dist/app/browser/en
dist/app/browser/es
dist/app/server/en
dist/app/server/es

Question:
Why does SSR with localisation break direct access to URLs with route parameters? How can I ensure that routes with parameters are properly resolved when directly accessed?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
